# The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception - Certificado A3

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ssl, certificado-digital

Criei uma api em c# com .net 7 e estou tentando fazer o envio de um evento da reinf utilizando o método assíncrono.

Estou usando o seguinte código para enviar o evento:

```
private async Task<string> ReceberLoteEventosAsync(string urlenviolote, X509Certificate2 certificado, XmlElement arquivos){
HttpResponseMessage response;
    HttpClientHandler certHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        CheckCertificateRevocationList = false,
    };
    certHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificado);

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(certHandler))
    {
        var stringContent = new StringContent(arquivos.OuterXml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
        response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlenviolote, stringContent);
    };
    return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

}

O certificado que estou usando é A3. O erro ocorre quando efetuo o PostAsync.

Já tentei outra forma conforme visto em artigos aqui, o erro persiste.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12
};
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificado);
handler.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
    (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => {
        return true;
    };
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
var stringContent = new StringContent(arquivos.OuterXml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
var response = await client.PostAsync(urlenviolote, stringContent);

return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Os detalhes do erro são:

InnerException  {Avaliação de chamadas do método System.Exception.get_Message() no método nativo System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetRawData(object). Não há suporte para a avaliação de métodos nativos neste contexto.} System.Exception {System.Net.InternalException}

Comment: Boa vindas. A mensagem diz para ver a exception, lá possui detalhes melhores. Dá forma atual da pergunta não tem como termos certeza se o problema é de programação ou outro problema não relacionado. A pergunta atual é duplicata, deve continuar na [**pergunta original**](/questions/584835/the-ssl-connection-could-not-be-established-see-inner-exception), seguindo as orientações ja fornecidas, para que a pergunta original passe pela avaliação de 5 membros do site, para uma possível reabertura (desde que corrija os problemas). Os comentarios aqui serão bloqueados, pode comentar na original.